# Buen fin de semana

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Today I came across a Facebook post about weekend titled "**Buen Fin**". I know "happy weekend" translates as "**buen fin de semana**" and I reckon **buen fin** to be just an abbreviation. What I want to know from native speakers is, was this a one-off example that I came across or is it common for natives to abbreviate this phrase in real? **Buen fin de semana** does sound like quite a mouthful to me so I think **buen fin** would be a much easier way to wish someone a happy weekend. But I don't want to sound odd to native ears doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper abbreviation for `Buen fin de semana` in Spain is

> Buen **finde**

The expression `Buen Fin` has other meanings there:

> Quiero llevar este proyecto **a buen fin**.

But is not used to refer to the weekend, at least in Spain.

It seems that in México `El Buen Fin` is used to designate an [special event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Buen_Fin):

> El Buen Fin (**Literally the "The Good End" but implying "The Good Weekend"**) is an annual nationwide shopping event in Mexico, in existence since 2011 and taking place on the third weekend of November in Mexico, and the beginning of the Christmas shopping season.

(Please, note the difference between the meaning of the expression and the *implied* meaning for the specific event)

So it is a sales/shopping event, like Black Friday (friday after Thanksgiving in the States), that takes place in a weekend. Probably what you saw in Facebook was an ad.

Comment: Yes, "buen fin" is not a native expression, nor sounds normal. But the abbreviations are fashionable today, perhaps intended to be done frequently. Or maybe it was a mistake.

Comment: @Rodrigo, I updated the answer. It seems that it refers to a specific commercial event, so there is some kind of word play with the literal meaning and an implied meaning. It seems, according to the reference, that the "good end" (literal meaning) of the event was Mexican President Felipe Calderón's belief that this move will cushion Mexican economy from the threats of European and US economic difficulties.

Comment: @Rodrigo, I think it does actually sound normal. Before the event was created, it was pretty normal to hear people say each other “¡Buen fin!” when saying goodbye at Friday evening, for example. And, furthermore, that's the main reason it became the name of the event, because it was already commonly used.

Comment: OK. I had not ever heard, so I generalized, sorry.

Comment: Buen finde for me sounds weird,I prefer buen fin.

Comment: @JaimeCruzTriana, where are you from? Is that form used outside Mexico?

Comment: Yo uso mucho `buen fin` para referirme a buen fin de semana, soy de cuba

Comment: "Buen finde" is also used in Argentina

Answer (score 7):

In my experience, “Buen fin” is a totally common phrase, meaning something like “Have a nice weekend”. The literal translation would be “Que tengas un buen fin de semana”, but few people say that because it's too long (but it may be appropiate in a formal context).

Also note that “fin” itself is also used with the meaning of “weekend”, such as “¿Qué vas a hacer este fin?” (“What will you do this weekend?”) and “¿Qué tal tu fin?” (“How was your weekend?”).

As Diego already pointed out, it's probable that what you saw actually was an ad for [El Buen Fin](http://www.elbuenfin.org/), a Black-Friday-like event. The name of this event is such because people already say “buen fin”, and they want to convey that a nice weekend will be a shopping weekend.

**Edit**: I think the confusion with Diego is that he is from Spain and I'm from Mexico. It seems that it's a Mexican idiom rather than a generalized one.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was just about to ask you that question. Hehe.

Comment: Similar usages are common in Venezuela as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Buen Fin" is a short form of saying "Buen fin de semana". But for extra reference, most recently, "Buen Fin" reefers to Mexican Marketer's attempt to create a "Black Friday" equivalent in Mexico.